# Construir un archivo JSON trayendo información de dos tablas

Tags: php, mysql

tengo dos tablas relacionadas entre si por dos columnas, y necesito traer información de la tabla dos según estas dos columnas.

**Tabla 1**

```
id | time | ruta |  destino  |
------------------------------
1  | 1hr  | M17  |  Town     |
2  | 24m  | M11  |  Town     |
```

**Tabla 2**

```
id | ref  | ruta |  destino  |
------------------------------
1  | A01  | M17  |  Town     |
2  | A08  | M17  |  Town     |
3  | A09  | M17  |  Town     |
4  | A11  | M17  |  Town     |
5  | A41  | M11  |  Town     |
6  | A15  | M11  |  Town     |
```

Necesito seleccionar de la tabla 2 la columna `ref`, trayendo todas las filas que correspondan a la relación, es decir si en la tabla 1 **ruta** es igual a **M17** y **destino** a **Town**, Entonces obtener de la tabla 2 la columna `ref` con todas sus filas que correspondan a esta solicitud, que nos de como resultado en JSON asi: `"ref":"A01, A08, A09, A11"` a continuación muestro como deberia quedar el JSON

```
[{
            "id":"1", 
            "ruta":"M17",           
            "destino":"Town",
            "ref":"A01, A08, A09, A11",
        },{
            "id":"2", 
            "ruta":"M11",           
            "destino":"Town",
            "ref":"A41, A15",
        },
```

Mi query es este: `$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table1");` pero no se como contruirlo, estoy aprendiendo php, muchas gracias

Comment: La consulta que necesitas es la siguiente: `SELECT t1.id, t1.ruta, t1.destino, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.ref) ref FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ruta=t2.ruta AND t1.destino=t2.destino GROUP BY t1.ruta, t1.destino` ... luego metes los resultados en un array y creas el json con `json_encode`.

Answer (score 0):

Podríamos empezar definiendo bien como quedaría la consulta final.

```
SELECT T1.id, T1.ruta, T1.destino,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(T2.ref SEPARATOR ',')
       FROM    Tabla_2 AS T2
       WHERE   T1.ruta = T2.ruta 
               AND T1.destino = T2.destino) AS ref 
FROM   Tabla_1 AS T1;
```

Aquí te muestro el resultado de la consulta:

https://paiza.io/projects/FtzWVELE6pcv3yj_WHpvLw

Ahora, en PHP debes definir la conexión hacia la base de datos, supongo que es la variable `$con` que indicas en el ejemplo, si no es así, puedes definirla de la siguiente manera:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","usuario","contraseña","base de datos");
```

Debes reemplazar cada uno de los parámetros de acuerdo a tu configuración de la base de datos.

Teniendo lista la conexión, puedes ejecutar la consulta a través de la función `query` de la conexión:

```
$result = $con->query("SELECT T1.id, T1.ruta, T1.destino,
                        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(T2.ref SEPARATOR ',')
                         FROM    Tabla_2 AS T2
                         WHERE   T1.ruta = T2.ruta 
                         AND T1.destino = T2.destino) AS ref 
                       FROM   Tabla_1 AS T1");
```

Si la consulta se ejecutó correctamente la variable `$result` contendrá un objeto con el resultado, de lo contrario tendrá el valor de `FALSE`.

En caso de tener resultados, deberás definir una variable tipo `array` para lugar realizar un cast de tu variable `$result` a un arreglo de resultados.

Finalmente, el arreglo resultante lo puedes mostrar como `JSON` haciendo uso de la función `json_encode()`.

Entonces puedes realizar esa validación:

```
if ($result === TRUE){

    $outp = array();
    $outp = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    echo json_encode($outp);  
}
```

Para más información sobre `json_encode()` puedes consultar la documentación oficial de PHP en español:

> http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php